# Find iOS Calendars

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, ios4

I have an app that creates a calendar event programmatically it is working and I just made it so it retrieves the users calendars and displays them in a picker but I have a memory leak. Can you see it becasue I tried releasing everything... In addition my main issue is how do I have it save to that calendar that the user selects, [event setCalendar:calendararray]; doesn't work. The calendararray is a EKCalendar *calendararray and I am setting the user selected calendar to it. Why does this not work???? How do I make it work...

calendar .m

```
 #import "calendar.h"


 @implementation calendar
 @synthesize delegate;
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

/* These are the calendar types an iOS Device can have. Please note
 that the "type" property of an object of type EKCalendar
 is of type EKCalendarType. The values in the "CalendarTypes"
 array reflect the exact same values in the EKCalendarType
 enumeration, but as NSString values */
NSArray *calendarTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          @"Local",
                          @"CalDAV",
                          @"Exchange",
                          @"Subscription",
                          @"Birthday",
                          nil];

/* Go through the calendars one by one */
NSUInteger counter = 1;
for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in eventStore.calendars){

    /* The title of the calendar */
    NSLog(@"Calendar %lu Title = %@", 
          (unsigned long)counter, thisCalendar.title);
```

Answer (score 3):

EKEventStore has a [calendars](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009567) property which is an NSArray of EKCalendar instances. You can then get each EKCalendar's title and display all of them to the user so they can select the calendar they wish to add the new event to.

Comment: Ok that showed me how to get somewhere, I found code to display it in the log, but I have looked around and can't find how to convert it to a string I posted the code above. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSLog(@"Calendar %lu Title = %@", (unsigned long)counter, thisCalendar.title);
NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Calendar %lu Title = %@", (unsigned long)counter, thisCalendar.title];
NSLog(title);
```

Comment: but what u did only gives me one cal at a time so i can't put it in a table right?

Comment: You have to do it in your for loop.

Comment: What does this code accomplish besides logging the same thing twice?

Comment: Ah, I see, answer to OP's comment on smountcastle's answer. Nevermind!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if all the code you posted is from the same version, but if you threw that together I'd see at least the following problem:

You say

```
[event setCalendar:calendararray];
```

doesn't work.

It seems `calendararray` ist set in `eventview.m`'s `calendararray:` method.

This in turn is called from `calendar.m`'s `pickerView:didSelectRow:`, where it takes the selected object from `arrayColors`.

In `calendar.m`'s `viewDidLoad` method, `arrayColors` is initialised with the users's calendars' titles, not the calendars.
So you end up giving `EKEvent`'s `setCalendar:` method an `NSString` instead of an `EKCalendar`.

Not knowing the rest of your program, as a fix I would try to keep the `EKCalendar` objects themselves in `arrayColors`.

So, in `calendar.m` try to change the

```
    [arrayColors addObject:thisCalendar.title];
```

in `viewDidLoad` to

```
    [arrayColors addObject:thisCalendar];
```

Then change `pickerView:titleForRow:` to

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {
   EKEvent *event = [arrayColors objectAtIndex:row]
   return event.title;
}
```

FInally, in `eventview.m` change `calendararray:`

```
- (void) calendararray:(EKCalendar *)array{
NSLog(@"calendarNameTextFieldStringFromTable %@", array);

calendararray = array;
calendarLabel.text = array.title;
calendarLabel.textColor = [UIColor brownColor];

}
```

Comment: On a more general note:

* do you get any warnings when you compile this? you should, and they should help you find the problems

Comment: * please don't edit your question to be a completely different one (i.e. "how do I find all the user's calendars?" vs. "setting a a specific calendar for an event does not work for me"); open a new question instead; otherwise the answers people gave for the first version of the question will seem nonsensical for new readers who will only see the latest version of the question

Comment: * the calendararray: method looks suspicious regarding memory management; the array should probably be retained (take a look at the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html), especially the part on [Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAccessorMethods.html]).

Comment: * you are confusing readers (and probably yourself) with your variable names (calendararray is no array, arrayColors has nothing to do with colors, etc.)

Comment: Yes I have tried the above I got It to work with bits from all over but can you help me with an error I'm getting. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352689/ekcalendar-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
#import "EventTestViewController.h"

#import "EventKit/EventKit.h"

@implementation EventTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = @"EVENT TITLE";

    event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];       
}
```

Comment: Its saving in the "calendar" not the work one which is what i picked

Answer (score 0):

Ok i see what you want, heres my way:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSArray *calendarArray = [eventStore calendars]; //Here you get all the device calendars

EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title = @"Event Title";

event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init]; event.endDate = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:816 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[calendarArray objectAtIndex:1]]; //here you set which calendar you want.. 
NSError *err;
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

You can NSLog with a FOR loop iterating "index" using this code below, to know which one you want.

```
 NSLog(@"Cal name> %@. Index of cal> %i", [[calendarArray objectAtIndex:index] title], index);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I have tried the above I got It to work with bits from all over but can you help me with an error I'm getting. Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352689/ekcalendar-error

Comment: Of course, I will have a look! If you got it to work please close this question by selecting the most appropriate answer as correct, the green tick.