# EKCalendar Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, calendar

I have an app that programmatically saves an EKEvent to you iOS calendar. Instead of it going to the default calendar you choose the calendar you wish it to be placed in. I am having a problem with the way you are picking it because some calendars work but not others.

Comment: You get that error when you save to the `eventStore`, or when you `setCalendar:` ?

Comment: when I try to save the event into the calendar

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your event's calendar twice

```
[event setCalendar:c]; 
[event setCalendar:[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:calendararray]];
```

Please tell me where do you get `calendararray` is it an array? i seems more like an indexKey.

---

Instead of passign the index of your selected calendar, pass its title, like this: `[calendar title]` or `calendar.title`. then using this title look for the one in the complete list of edit and noneditable.

---

**UPDATE**

Just do something like this:

```
EKCalendar *theSelectedCalendar;
// selectedCalendarTitle comes from your delegate instead of your index...

for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in eventStore.calendars){
    if ([thisCalendar.title isEqualToString:selectedCalendarTitle]){
       [event setCalendar:thisCalendar];
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
EKCalendar *theSelectedCalendar;
// selectedCalendarTitle comes from your delegate instead of your index...

for (int i=0; i<=([eventStore.calendars count]-1); i++) {
    if ([[[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:i] title] isEqualToString:selectedCalendarTitle]){
       [event setCalendar:[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:i]];
    } 
}
```

---

**UPDATE 3**

```
//Present the picker populated with the array: eventStore.calendars. This should return the index and store it in: indexOfSelectedCalendarFromEventSoreCalendars

if ([[[eventStore calendars] objectAtIndex:indexOfSelectedCalendarFromEventSoreCalendars] allowsContentModifications]){
  [event setCalendar:[[eventStore calendars] objectAtIndex:indexOfSelectedCalendarFromEventSoreCalendars]];

} else {
    NSLog(@"Selected calendar cannot be modified."); //Present the picker again for the user to select another calendar.
}
```

Comment: they are in 2 separate views so I use a delegate and it transfers the row index of the picker to int calendarArray;

Comment: have you checked the value of the variable?

Comment: "debug" your app and inspect what is the value of the variable being transfered by your delegate.  Can you also `NSLog(@"%@",[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:calendararray])` right before you setCalendar?

Comment: with it adding the object in the modification if         if (thisCalendar.allowsContentModifications == YES){
            NSLog(@"Calendar %lu can be modified.", 
                  (unsigned long)counter);
          
           [arrayColors addObject:cal];

Comment: dont pass the index, pass the name of the calendar, so you can look for it instead of using objectAtIndex

Comment: //  EKCalendar *theSelectedCalendar;
            // selectedCalendarTitle comes from your delegate instead of your index...
            
            for (EKCalendar *thisCalendar in eventStore.calendars){
                if ([thisCalendar.title isEqualToString:selectedCalendarTitle]){
                    [event setCalendar:thisCalendar];
                }
            }

Comment: Never find you can find the file here http://www.brandonsdesigngroup.com/ical.zip thanks for your help I think we are close to the answer.

Comment: aha! i see where the error is! (i think) Let me code you a solution and i will update my answer.

Comment: It crashed I got an error. Thread1 program received signal: sigabrt on the Line....    if ([[[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:i] title] isEqualToString:selectedCalendarTitle]){

Comment: this is awkward. let me check again

Comment: Sorry I missed the -1. But now it's the old error that there is no calendar set...

Comment: oh i was really looking for another solution to the -1, great. Now that should be something we can debug this way: try setting `[event setCalendar:[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:1]];` without that code i gave you, that should set some existing calendar, tell me if that works

Comment: And that wasn't based on the picker were u just testing if that line was the problem?

Comment: yes that indeed, What i said about the index, was that at the beginning you told me that you were having an index of an array filtered by "isEditable", and that index would not be the same in your eventstore.calendars. so we needed something that could identify the selected calendar, and then look in the complete array for it, but now when we identify it we cannot set it as the setCalendar:

Comment: So this is not possible... How do all these other apps do it.

Comment: Hey it is possible! i do it in my apps, i just cant get it to work within your app, there must be something i dont see

Comment: i dont use that filtered array nor pass by delegate any var but yes, i use [event setCalendar:[[eventStore calendars]objectAtIndex:theIndexOfMyPickerWithoutFilter]];

Comment: So u don't filter but if they make an appointment how does it save if it's not editable??

Comment: Whenever the user selects a calendar for saving i check if the event can be saved to that calendar. that was the simplest way i came up with.

Comment: Ok how do you do that and if you can't then you have them select a different calendar? How do u check what is the code to check

Comment: If you dont want to it's fine but what is another to do it. U said u were looking into another way of using the -1

Comment: Do u have any other ways of doing this

Comment: You populate the Picker with the whole array of eventstore.calendars, then whenever the user selects a cal, you check with the way you filtered the array if it can be editable. if it can, you setClanedar: with that array index.

Comment: How do u do an if with just the editable calendars? Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: Thanks and other than that there is no way to do it how we originally tried like the apple calendar.. Do you have a calendar app on the store? Which one. Just wondering doesn't make a difference.

Comment: It should work the way we started, though i cant manage to see why i doesn't.. Does this suits your needs?

Comment: The other way would save me about 30 hours of re programing. I gave my files above can u see if you can get it to work and than send it to me. I appreciate all of your time. I really do. Thanks.

Comment: Post your whole .m and .h file and i will take a look. because i cant understand where the error is with what you posted.